# AWS cognito is giving serializationException(Start of structure or map found where not expected) while doing sign up in node.js How to fix this issue?

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to add signup functionality with AWS cognito, But While signing up up getting `SerializationException` How to resolve this issue?

My **signup** function look like this

```
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require("amazon-cognito-identity-js");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
global.fetch = require("node-fetch");

const keys = require("../../config/keys");

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: keys.awsKeys.key,
    secretAccessKey: keys.awsKeys.secret,
    region: keys.region.awsRegionId
});

const poolConfig = {
    UserPoolId: keys.cognito.userPoolId,
    ClientId: keys.cognito.clientId
};

// create a new user pool
const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolConfig);

async function signupFunc(userData) {
    console.log('JSON string received : ' + JSON.stringify(userData));

    const emailData = {
        Name: "email",
        Value: userData.email
    };

    const name = {
        Name: "name",
        Value: userData.name
    }

    const password = userData.password;

    const familyname = {
        Name: 'family_name',
        Value: userData.familyname
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            var attributeList = [];

            attributeList.push(new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(name));
            attributeList.push(new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(familyname));

            userPool.signUp(emailData, password, attributeList, null, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(`ERROR : ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
                    return reject({ status: 0, error: "Error!!!" });
                }

                return resolve({
                    status: "200",
                    message: "Check email and verify!"
                });

            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`ERROR : ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
            return reject({error: error});
        }
    });
}

module.exports = signupFunc;
```

*While executing this method I'm getting below exception.*

```
{
   "code":"SerializationException",
   "name":"SerializationException",
   "message":"Start of structure or map found where not expected."
}
```

any help will much appreciated.

Comment: Did you got the solution for the same?

Comment: Yes I got a solution I will update it soon

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, because I was mistakenly passing the password as an `Object` instead of a `String`. Make sure you password is a **`String`**:

```
Auth.completeNewPassword(user, password, {} ).then(data=> console.log(data)})
```

Here user is an `Object` and password is a `String`.